# Load xml layout in java class and edit its objects (Android studio)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I got a LinearLayout which i want it to be added to main layout multiple times. Here is the xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/lay">



<TextView
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="top|end"
    android:textColor="#9b9e96" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/user"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="109dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/commentaire" />
```

So far i could load it using Inflater like this :

```
 LayoutInflater l = getLayoutInflater();
 View v = l.inflate(R.layout.commentaire, null);
```

[image]

Here is what i got so far using a loop and is what I wanted.

However I want to edit those TextViews using

```
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
        tv.setText("whatever");
```

But I always get

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

It seems that the TextView tv is null. Any ideas how to edit objects inside the layout ?
Thanks

Comment: If you are inflating it. you need to set the parent view to the findViewById.  For example in your case,  Change the findViewById to;  TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);

Comment: Show java code fully.

Comment: Quick answer and it's working. Thanks a lot man!